# Find the number of composition series of D24 (with 24 elements)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I got this question and trying to find a way that is not fully brute force.

I found a composition series which is of length 4, so i know they are all of length 4. looking at the divisors of 24 we have $1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24$. so the corresponding sizes, by Lagrange's theorem can be:

Case 1: $1,3,6,12,24$

Case 2: $1,2,4,12,24$

Case 3: $1,2,4,8,24$

From here on I'm stuck. I can't see anything by brute force finding almost every subgroup of $D24$. Is there a better way? or maybe finding subgroups isn't too hard?

Thanks!

Comment: Use that $G/N$ is abelian if and only if $G' \subseteq N$. So the possible penultimate terms of a composition series of $G$ correspond to the maximal subgroups of the abelian group $G/G'$. If you have found such a penultimate term $N$, go on by considering $N/N'$ and so on...

Comment: Btw: A composition series consisting of five subgroups has length four. You have to count the number of inclusions, not the number of subgroups.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and correction. i actually didn't study the derivative group yet, so should do it somehow without using it.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\normal}{\trianglelefteq}$
I think there's a nice recursive way of decomposing $D_n$ (I'm going to use this notation to mark the group with $2n$ elements) when $n=2^k \cdot p$ for some prime $p$ (which is your case for $n=12$). Let $D_n = \left<\rho, \varepsilon \right>$ where $\rho^n=1$ and $\varepsilon^2=1$. If $n$ is even then $N=\left<\rho^2,\varepsilon\right>$ is a normal subgroup as it has index $2$. For the same reason, this shows that the quotient group is simple.

Next, you can show that $N_1 \cong D_{n/2}$. Now you continue in the same manner until you get $N_k \cong D_{n/2^k}=D_p$. At this point we know that $p$ is prime, and you can check that the normal subgroups are $\left<\rho^d \right>\cong \mathbb{Z}_{n/(2^k\cdot d)}$ for any $d \ | \ n/2^k=p$, thus the only proper normal subgroup is $\left<\rho\right> \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$, which finishes the composition series, since the next subgroup must be $\{1\}$.

This gives you one possible composition series, in your case it is:
$$\{e\}\underset{\mathbb{Z}_3}{ \normal} \mathbb{Z}_3  \underset{\mathbb{Z}_2}{ \normal} D_3 \underset{\mathbb{Z}_2}{ \normal} D_{6} \underset{\mathbb{Z}_2}{ \normal} D_{12}$$
and you can simply check the permutations of the quotient orders to see if you have other possibilities

Comment: Much thanks! regarding the last part, the permutations of the quotients is reflected in the 3 cases.. the problem is how do i know how much series exist for each case.. you showed an example for case 1, i found another one with the cycle of rotations subgroup of order 12. how do i know if there are more? i know whenever i have a cyclic group it's quite easy. but for example i have the problem: how many subgroups of order 8 are there, and for each one how many subgroups of order 4, and etc.. seems impossible

Comment: Write down all the normal subgroups of $D_n$, there aren't a lot (note that they differ if $n$ is odd or even). Then you cam simply check all cases at each step in the series.

Comment: I see. but for example i want to find all normal subgroups of order 12, which means all subgroups of order 12, i found two and it seems like there are no more, how do i prove it? i thought that maybe i can go over all pairs of elements and singletones and look at the groups they generate, but also seems like too much work. is this they only way?

Comment: Use the fact that normal subgroups are unions of conjugation classes. Think about the form of conjugacy classes in $D_n$, they are pretty "well" ordered. Once you have those written down (again, they differ for odd/even $n$) think about the size of the subgroup induced by taking various unions, you'll see that there aren't a lot of options.